# Can I change the position of myLocation button on HuaweiMap?

Tags: android, huawei-map-kit

I know the button for myLocation set with        `map.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true` is placed at the bottom right of the HuaweiMap. Is there any way I can change it's position?